# simulate keypress on background app

Tags: macos, swift

I'm making an OSX app (for an art project) that runs in the background recording and reacting to user input. I figured out how to track key presses when the app is in the background, but I can't figure out how to simulate those key presses and update the app while it's running in the background.

First the code to track the keypress while the app is in the background. This is in my viewDidLoad function -

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDownMask, handler: handleKeyDownEvent);
```

below is the corresponding even listener function where I thought maybe I could simulate the keypress by using CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent but it updates the focused app not the app in the background -

```
func handleKeyDownEvent(event:NSEvent!) {
    //try to simulate a keyboard press that updates background app
    println("key down is \(event.keyCode)");
    var e:CGEventRef = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(nil, 7, true).takeRetainedValue();
    CGEventPost(CGEventTapLocation(kCGHIDEventTap), e);
    //CFRelease(e);how do I use CFRelease in swift?
}
```

any ideas would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: To what app are you hoping to deliver the event? You can try sending the event directly to the target app using `CGEventPostToPSN()`, but I don't know of any non-deprecated API for getting the `ProcessSerialNumber` (PSN) for an app. Also, when an app is not active, there's no good reason to believe that it will do something meaningful with a key event. Just because you want to achieve something doesn't mean that you can. Finally, you don't use `CFRelease()` in Swift. Calling `takeRetainedValue()` on the unmanaged object gave you a managed object which Swift will do the memory management for.

Comment: Thanks Ken Thomases, The app I'm hoping to deliver the event to is the same app I'm tracking keypresses in - so maybe I don't need to get the PSN because it wouldn't have to reference a separate app, it would reference itself? A more basic description of what I'm trying to achieve is I just want the app to run like it's focused when it's in the background, not sure if there's an easier way to achieve this. A description of the project is - users play a game in one room while their keypresses drive a painting app that is being projected in a separate room.

Comment: Why do you need to receive the key event in any way other than the global event monitor that you're already using? Why can't your `handledKeyDownEvent()` method do what you want without having to re-post the event to itself?

Comment: The handleKeyDownEvent isn't updating/affecting the app when it's in the background, it's just tracking the keypresses. I was thinking I could somehow update/affect the app while it's in the background/not focused.

Comment: You can. You just need to code `handleKeyDownEvent()` to do what you want. There's no point re-posting the event. Just write the code to do what your app should do in response to a key event. If your app were the active app, what would it do in response to key events? How would those events be handled and by what code?